# How big does a floating island have to be for the effects of motion sickness to be negated?

Tags: science-based, technology, engineering, macroengineering

Assuming a floating island is built from plastic trash or barrels how big would it have to be for motion sickness to become irrelevant?

Comment: You have picked two mutually exclusive tags, so please pick one and add also other relevant tags, none of them is self standing

Comment: Hello Jacob. Please read the tag wikis before using any tag. The wikis for [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science] both specifically state that you can use one or the other... but not both. Your question cannot (and should not) be answered until you select one of the two tags plus supporting tags. NOTE: Especially read the [tag:hard-science] tag wiki. That tag is ruthless and exists for a specific purpose. Answers that don't meet the wiki's requirements get deleted.

Comment: @L.Dutch @JoinJBH how come the `science-based` and `hard-science` are exclusive? To my mind the `Science-based` does  not _require_ scientific citations but does not forbid them (no, "contrast" does not necessarily mean either-or, the later would require "as opposed to/in opposition with"). Any `hard-science` answer is implicitly a `science-based`. If there's a sin the question committed, is that both require an extra domain for the `science` part, can't be used alone.

Comment: Hmm. I can sleep on a 22ft trailer sailer while it is on anchor (aka bobbing up and down) or under sail without getting motion sick. Chances are I could sleep on a 2m square raft of trash and not get motion sick. Probably not universal to all people and all sea conditions.

Comment: Is the floating trash island rigid or amorphous? If it's amorphous, wave action will go straight through and affect everything on the "island" but if it's rigid (really questionable with something made of garbage), then we need to know how big the waves involved are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sickness#:~:text=The%20cause%20of%20motion%20sickness,diagnosis%20is%20based%20on%20symptoms.

Comment: It's not about size, it's about speed (both rral and perceived). If the island is stationary people on it will not be affected.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi, (a) I'm having trouble believing you've read the tag wikis. (b) A long time ago the Stack developed the idea of trying to identify just how strictly answers should adhere to Real Life science. At this point, there are tags that specifically identify just how much science should constrain the answers. What, then, is the point of using both tags when one says an answer can be creative so long as science is used as a baseline and the other says an answer cannot be creative because science is absolutely required? (\*continued\*)

Comment: After reading both tag wikis, please read [this answer of mine to a Meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8282/40609) that expands on the issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after a day the OP has not returned to clarify mutually exclusive tags or to clarify the question.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact [this is fair enough](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8282/40609) - because it exposes the rationale for the choice. While "(a) I'm having trouble believing you've read the tag wikis." is unfair, because I **did** read those and I still asked for a _reason/rationale_ - should be a sign that the descriptions of the tags _let enough room for interpretation_ (especially for people with English as a second language). Whenever the same issue pops up, I suggest linking to the Meta-question in addition to just the one to the plain link. Otherwise... (ctnd)

Comment: ... it may let the impression of a community stewarded by authority rather than based on rational choices (imperfect as they may be)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi If you have issues understanding these tags, you should ask this on the meta-site :). In regard to the question, it seems there is a misconception regarding what is motion sickness and how it is actually triggered. Should check how people cope with it (like on boats), but also for virtual reality equipment, for instance in order to have a better grasp on its mechanisms.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The place to ask such questions is never in the comments to a question. They belong on Meta. Note that reasons and rationale will always fail - but the clarity of the mutually exclusive nature of the tags left no room whatsoever for interpretation. You might not have understood or liked the "why" for the rule - but you couldn't have misunderstood the rule.

Comment: You need to specify whether your floating island is floating on water, or in the sky.

Comment: @Adrian Colomitch: But isn't stewarded by arbitrary authority the actual situation?

Answer (score 9):

Motion sickness is a lot like sex: size does not really matter, and what ruins your experience is unmet expectations. [So says Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_sickness)

> Motion sickness occurs due to a difference between actual and expected motion.

Standing on a floating island might be a lot like standing on the top of a mountain. If the island is stationary or feels stationary, people on it will not feel sick.

I have motion sickness and rollercoasters suck to me. Being inside an airplane, though, is ok because for most of the trip they seem stationary. I know they are moving at hundreds of km/h (or mph, at this scale it doesn't matter), but except for turbulences and the food, it's a quite enjoyable experience. I am also ok on boats and ships of all sizes, even when the sea is not calm... Jet skis suck to me, though. Those trigger my motion sickness, even though they don't accelerate as much as an airplane. Maybe because the water and waves feel so close.

So I say that unless your floating island is a small piece of rock no larger than a car, people on it should be fine.

Comment: Nice!  I think you need to add your insight as regards sex to the wikipedia article.

Comment: yeah, did read papers on that motion sickness, as a result of some clarifications in comments here, such a complex subject, and I would say "unmet expectation" - yep, sums it well.

Answer (score 1):

- Must be rigid - otherwise this happens

[image: if not rigid]

- Must be longer/wider than at least the longest wave-length of the sea waves.
  If it shorter on the transversal to the wave direction, this happens

[image: shorter than wavelen]

- If at about the same wave-length, it will need [ship stabilizers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_(ship)). Either increasing the momentum of inertia to resist rolling around the axis (heavy as hell or using gyroscopes) or active fin stabilizers. Otherwise this happens

[image: at wave length]

- Your best bet is a rigid structure with the size at twice or more the largest wave length that you are likely to encounter

[image: twice wave length]

A table in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind_wave#Formation) lists the average wave-length in strong wind conditions (92 km/h) to a value of 212m. So you'll need a rigid island about 500m across.

Comment: At a certain size, even if semi flexible the "island" will have a damping effect on the waves and the center will be mostly calm. I suspect a 500 km wide island would be mostly calm.

Comment: Depends on how well the semi-flexibility is achieved. If not engineered on purpose and with care to materials fatigue, it won't stay flexible for long, it will stat disintegrating from the sides towards the center. A very likely scenario anyway for a "plastic trash or barrels" floating island, no matter the size.

Comment: noting is rigid, at least for what we have, on the scale of  500m. Ja0ans had some project, like big floating raft thing(is I remember correctly) and they considered to have high buildings there, maybe would be nice to find that project information for this type of answer

Answer (score 1):

**Floating island inhabitants should be anchored**

I only mention this because you've used science-tags: there is no magic... Like everything else, your island exists because of the laws of nature. If you follow Newton, floating islands *could* exist with a styrofoam planet under it, or mass can be in low orbit because of large speed.. but that would not count as "floating". Also, how would the atmosphere be contained, without relevant gravity ?

Assuming *population* on these islands is kind of awkward.. Animals, or civilized inhabitants on a floating island will experience the same near zero gravity. The inhabitants would either fly, or be very small, attached to the bottom or the top. Non-flying species remain on the top, anchored to their island, else they float away into space.

Inhabitants originating from a planet surface, like humans, would have to take some safety precautions.. and probably won't survive on the island. They need means to return to the surface.. or to their home planet.

**Some notes on local evolution**

While the ecology of your island is isolated, there will be no issue with motion sickness. Evolution on the island will avoid motion sickness in the first place. You can't have species wiggling and vomiting all the time, instead of searching for food. Also, the low gravity circumstances will cause any species to be very small.

Species able to fly will have a big advantage over other species bound to the island. I do not know, what conditions would cause birds or insects to experience motion sickness. Motion sickness is something that occurs in mammals used to the ground, when their [sense of balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_of_balance) becomes disturbed.

**Even if afflicted by motion sickness, perceived movement will be too slow**

The cause of motion sickness is resonance. This resonance results from atmospheric density, winds, size, and gravity. I leave stability issues to Adrian and the other answers, but considering very low-gravity circumstances, I don't expect strong motion, like a ship on a stormy sea. A strong wind would require a heavy atmosphere and it can blow the island apart. Resonance frequencies in such circumstances will become very low, as a result the motion experienced would also be very slow.

I enclose the pendulum frequency formula, as you see having low G will increase the period of oscillation T,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a sailor **get motion sickness from standing on the solid concrete dock**, which just proves that motion sickness is an incredibly subjective thing.

Personally, I have gotten motion sickness from sitting at a table on the 75th floor of a skyscraper, that was apparently *very gently* swaying in the wind. I have also stood (clung desperately) to the deck of a fishing trawler in Scale 8 waves (30-50ft waves!!), with no motion sickness at all.

It is hugely subjective and situational.

Answer (score 0):

Your island will have motion sickness, period.

To avoid motion sickness you need your object to be large enough that waves average out.  The problem is your island is made of weak materials, it can't take the forces that would cause.  Thus your island is going to have to flex with the waves and can't shield you from motion sickness.